# Why were instead of had been

Tags: past-tense

I received a letter from x yesterday. We **were** at school but I lost touch with him because he was very ill and could not go to school anymore.

why it is not "had been" at school, is it because in the first sentence there is yesterday so "going to school with him" is obviously before  this event  (the receiving of the letter)

If yesterday was not written would it be judicious to use the past perfect
I received a letter 3 years ago, it was from x . We had been at school but had lost touch with him because was very ill and could not go to school anymore

Comment: There is no reason why the writer should not have used **We had been at school** (did you leave out **together**?) The length of time since the receipt of the letter makes no difference. It's just the writer's choice.

Comment: if both are ok , why should the author choose one form rather than another . using past simple should not connect  receiving with the fact of having been at school :is that correct ?

Comment: _We don't know_ why the author chose one tense rather than the other. Presumably the speaker is an adult. The second sentence explains how they came to know X; they were at school together in their youth, but lost touch long ago.

Comment: The fact that "being at school together" ***must*** precede "losing touch" is so obvious that there's no *reason* to explicitly reflect that by casting the earlier activity further into the past using a Perfect construction. As a general principle, it's better for even *competent writers* to avoid using more complex verb forms than necessary. And that principle applies even more strongly to non-native speakers, who often won't have sufficient background knowledge to know when to *deliberately* exercise the option to use a more complex verb form purely for "stylistic" reasons.

Comment: (You'll note that Kate used Simple Past in the final sentence of her preceding comment - probably without even *thinking* about the fact that she *could* have written *...they **had been** at school together in their youth, but lost touch long ago.* Why complicate things?)

Comment: my question is not about the tense of lost but about the tense of being at school . Choosing past simple "was at school" makes me think that it was not a long time ago or at least it was not fully completed. In fact I want to know why even  if the author chose past simple we  understand that being in school happened before receiving a letter