# Why without using past perfect we understand that an event takes place before another one

Tags: past-tense

I received a letter from x yesterday. We **were** at school together but I lost touch with him because he was very ill and could not go to school anymore.

Why without using past perfect I understand that school was before I received a letter. I really don't understand why because as it comes after the first sentence we could understand that the event (going to school ) happens after

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please don't do this. It is so annoying./

Comment: Virtual duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303993/why-were-instead-of-had-been

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context and pragmatics

If you said

> I got a letter from X today.  I was reading it on the bus.

You know that the reading must come after receiving the letter.  You don't know this from the grammar but from what you know about how letters work.  You can't read them before you receive them.

But

> I got a letter from X today.  I was hoping for it on the bus.

You "hope for" something before receiving it.  Identical grammar, but different timeline.  You could rephrase this with past perfect - perhaps you *should* rephrase it. But grammatically its not essential.

> I got a letter from X today. We were at school together.

You know that people who are at school together today don't tend to write letters to each other.  This is how friendships work.

This is confirmed by what comes after about "losing touch.  If you lost touch after being at school, then you can't have been at school today, after receiving the letter.  That is what "losing touch" means.

> I got a letter from X today. We were at school together, and I hadn't opened it because I thought it was strange.  I asked him why he sent me a letter and he said that there are some things you can only say with a pen.

**There is nothing special about English**  any language (with or without a tense system) can express this and any speaker of that language can put together a coherent timeline.